# Roles in spring-mvc with different classes

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

If I have a superclass `User`, and classes `Student` and `Lecturer` extending this class, what is the best way to use roles (i.e. for security) in the `springBoot` application.

I feel like it is almost not necessary because I have two classes anyway?

Answer (score 2):

Using the class types as roles is not a very good idea as it is not flexible. Lets say you create a user that is a `Student` and persist it into database table called `student`. If you later want to change the role of this user to a `Lecturer`, you will have to migrate all the users data to a new table.

A common approach that I often see being used is having a intermediate class (table) which holds all the available roles. Then each user has a list of roles (or only one role). This way you can easily change what roles apply to different users.

For example lets say you have a basic role class:

```
class Role {

    String name;

    // Getters and setters...
}
```

Then your student and lecturer classes would look something like this:

```
abstract class User {

    List<Role> roles;

    // Easy way to check if a user has a role (better approach would be to use a Set).
    boolean hasRole(String name) {
        for (Role r : roles) {
            if (name.equals(r.getName())) 
                return true
        }
        return false
    }
}

class Lecturer extends User {
}

class Student extends User {
}
```

This type of role structure has one obvious benefit - it will be very easy to change roles for the users on your database.

Also you can create multiple tiny roles. For example a `Lecturer` could have the roles `read`, `write`, `create` and so on, which would grant him all the rights to your application. While the student might only have the `read` role.

I would also suggest to checkout [Spring Security](https://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) if you plan to implement some sort of authentication to you application (it also follows a similar method of roles that I've described).

Comment: +1 for mentioning lack of flexibility. Imagine a grad student who both a student in some classes and a lecturer in others.

Answer (score 0):

I would add security roles anyway.

You do not have to use this classes when handling every request. While authenticated user will have his roles "hide" in session tokens.

I am not sure if you can handle security problems only with two user classes.

And what about not authenticated users?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make security in your `spring boot`  app you could use `spring securtiy` which handles roles and make it easy for you , you could also create your own `succes handlers` and `failure handlers` classes :

first you add these lines on your `pom.xml` under `dependencies`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

you have to be able to manipulate  `thymleaf` for  login custom  forms wich is not complicated ,after defining `thymleaf` and `spring security` you need to define a configuration class and data source like i did in the code below

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;


import javax.sql.DataSource ;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {



 @Autowired 
public void GlobalConfig(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth,DataSource dataSource) throws Exception {
auth.jdbcAuthentication()
    .dataSource(dataSource) 
   //this is actually where your roles and your user class interferes  to login with different roles take this as exemple to your own need
    .usersByUsernameQuery("SELECT  login AS principal , password AS  credentials , true FROM utilisateur WHERE login =  ? ")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("SELECT  u.login AS principal , r.role as role  FROM utilisateur u ,role r where u.id_role=r.id_role AND login = ?  ");

}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring()
    .antMatchers("/angular/**","/css/**","/js/**","/assets/**");
    //this line to make full access of assets
}
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http

    .csrf().disable()   
    .authorizeRequests()
.antMatchers("/yourHomePages/ThatDoesn'tIncludeLogin") .permitAll()
    .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()        
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()      
            .logout()
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .permitAll();   
 }


}
```

after defining the configuration class and data sources you need to define `\login`  so you have to resolve the path by making `MvcResolver` like this

```
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
 import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
 import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;


@Configuration
public class WebMVCconfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");

  }
}
```

`viewName` is you custom login  that you'll create and it has to be under `src/main/resources/templates/`

for any further informations you could use these links
http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springsecurity.html ,https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleafexamples-springsecurity and also spring security official documentation